# Конвертер UI элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть ListView и мне нужно в зависимости от типа элемента в списке отображать разные ContextMenuStrip. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Не уверен, но скорей всего через `DataTemplate`, задаете ему `DataType` и прописываете шаблон элемента, который будет, если тот имеет тип, что в `DataType`.

Comment: а контекстное меню куда? на сами элементы в режиме выбора или на listview после того как элемент выбран?

Comment: Ackbar, контекстное меню на выбранном элементе, для работы с ним.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен следующий код:
XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Item1Template"
                      DataType="{x:Type local:Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="Item1" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Item2Template"
                      DataType="{x:Type local:Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="Item2" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Item3Template"
                      DataType="{x:Type local:Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="Item3" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <local:ItemTemplateSelector Item1Template="{StaticResource Item1Template}"
                                            Item2Template="{StaticResource Item2Template}"
                                            Item3Template="{StaticResource Item3Template}" />
            </ListView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

C#:
ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Items selectedItems;
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Items items = new Items();
                Item1 item1 = new Item1();
                item1.Id = 1;
                items.Item1s.Add(item1);
                Collection.Add(items);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Items items = new Items();
                Item2 item2 = new Item2();
                item2.Id = 2;
                items.Item2s.Add(item2);
                Collection.Add(items);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Items items = new Items();
                Item3 item3 = new Item3();
                item3.Id = 3;
                items.Item3s.Add(item3);
                Collection.Add(items);
            }

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Items> Collection { get; set; }

        public Items SelectedItems
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedItems;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

Items:

```
public class Items : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Items()
        {
            Item1s = new ObservableCollection<Item1>();
            Item2s = new ObservableCollection<Item2>();
            Item3s = new ObservableCollection<Item3>();
        }



        public ObservableCollection<Item1> Item1s { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Item2> Item2s { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Item3> Item3s { get; set; }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

Item1:

```
public class Item1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

Item2:

```
public class Item2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

Item3:

```
public class Item3 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

Также Вам нужен селектор, который выбирает нужный Вам шаблон для `ListViewItem`

```
public class ItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            DataTemplate template = null;
            Items items = item as Items;
            if (items.Item1s.Count > 0)
            {
                template = Item1Template;
                if (template == null)
                {
                    template = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
                }
            }
            else if (items.Item2s.Count > 0)
            {
                template = Item2Template;
                if (template == null)
                {
                    template = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
                }
            }
            else if (items.Item3s.Count > 0)
            {
                template = Item3Template;
                if (template == null)
                {
                    template = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                template = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
            }

            return template;
        }

        public DataTemplate Item1Template { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate Item2Template { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate Item3Template { get; set; }
    }
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что без MVVM это не реализовать, также надо понимать, что все UI элементы создаваться в XAML.